# Get unique data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get unique location from three tables, location should be unique in three table?

```
table1 : location = delhi   // location is column name in all three tables <br>
table2 : location = delhi
table3 : location = delhi
```

Result:

```
delhi
```

Comment: Add some more sample table data. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: table1, table2,table3 are mysal table and all tables have location column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.location = table2.location 
INNER JOIN table3 on table2.location = table3.location;
```

Answer (score 0):

use INTERSECT Operator for retrieving the above mentioned output.
you can read this as well [click here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/intersect.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    location
FROM
    table1
UNION
SELECT
    location
FROM
    table2
UNION
SELECT
    location
FROM
    table3
```

try this

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.